# Mocking HttpContext.Current using moq on NUnit Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nunit, moq

I am testing an MVC 3 controller that calls methods on this class:

```
public class SessionVar
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the session.
    /// </summary>
    private static HttpSessionState Session
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null)
                throw new ApplicationException
                                   ("No Http Context, No Session to Get!");

            return HttpContext.Current.Session;
        }
    }

    public static T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        return Session[key] == null ? default(T) : (T)Session[key];
    }
    ...
}
```

My test method, following recommendations from [Hanselman's Blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx) is:

```
[Test]
public void CanRenderEmployeeList()
{
    _mockIEmployeeService.Setup(s => s.GetEmployees(StatusFilter.OnlyActive))
        .Returns(BuildsEmployeeList().Where(e => e.IsApproved));

    var httpContext = FakeHttpContext();
    var target = _employeeController;
    target.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext
                  (new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()), target);
    var result = target.Index();

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<ViewResult>(result);
    var viewModel = target.ViewData.Model;
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<EmployeeListViewModel>(viewModel);
}

public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
{
    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);

    return context.Object;
}
```

But my test keeps failing, I get:

```
CanRenderEmployeeListSystem.ApplicationException : No Http Context, 
                                                          No Session to Get!
```

which is the Exception message to be thrown when `HttpContext.Current == null`

I just need the Session object to 'exist', not the actual values stored on the Session.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the long run, you'll be happier if you create an interface for the SessionVar class.  Use your current implementation (via Dependency Injection) at runtime.  Plug in a mock during testing.  Removes the need for mocking out all of those Http runtime dependencies.

Comment: This is what I ended doing, somehow it felt like a workaround... but then I found other people doing it the same way and after your comment here: the workaround feeling is almost disappearing :)

Answer (score 2):

The HttpContext.Current in your Session property isn't being affected by the the mocked HttpContextBase that you're creating.  That is, simply creating a local HttpContextBase doesn't automatically populate HttpContext.Current.  In fact HttpContext and HttpContextBase aren't actually related.  You have to use a HttpContextWrapper to unify them.

So you're better off passing an HttpContextWrapper implementation into your class SessionVar.  In the code below I've changed your method and property to instance level so that we can set the context in the constructor.  If no context is passed to the constructor we assume HttpContext.Current, but you can also pass your mocked instance in for your tests.

```
public class SessionVar
{
    HttpContextWrapper m_httpContext;

    public SessionVar(HttpContextWrapper httpContext = null)
    {
        m_httpContext = httpContext ?? new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the session.
    /// </summary>
    private HttpSessionState Session
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_httpContext == null)
                throw new ApplicationException("No Http Context, No Session to Get!");

            return m_httpContext.Session;
        }
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        return Session[key] == null ? default(T) : (T)Session[key];
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution too, but i prefer @PatrickSteele 's and in fact that was the one that I ended implementing. Thank you for your help.